# GCP Bigquery run issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a query in GCP console. The script is correct but it shows the below message while I run the query.

```
"Results are not displayed because the table has a large amount of cells and may cause the BigQuery console to become unresponsive. Consider modifying your query to improve browser performance."
```

What is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a **BigQuery's** mechanism to avoid overwhelming your browser.

You still can see the results by clicking on **View results**

If you think this message is confuse or something should be changed, I encourage you to create a Public Issue sharing your thoughts. You can do that through this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659)

Answer (score 0):

You may have potentially caused a humongous CROSS JOIN in your query. You need to take a look at your query first, and BigQuery will compute the results if you force it, but it will lead to the use of a lot of Slots and rack up a high bill for you